# Git keeps asking me to enter username and password

Tags: git, github

Recently, I generated a new personal access token on GitHub and then the problems started occurring. Earlier, I could easily clone a repository with HTTPS without entering username and password on Git. Also, I could easily push changes to a repository without entering username and password. But, now I have to enter username and password on a pop up every time I push changes or clone a repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just visit [this page](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password) on GitHub and follow the instructions:

- set credential helper first (explained clearly in the page)

  - for different types of credential helpers for different OSs' follow [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git)
- then on the next prompt for password use your PAT instead (again explained clearly)